# Problema con lastIndexOf de javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

Estoy realizando unas pruebas de métodos con String en java script y llegé a las métodos de indexOf y lastIndexOf, pero encuentro algo curioso que me llama la atención con el método **lastIndexOf** cuando se asigna el índice de donde debe de comenzar a realizar la búsqueda, es detalle es el siguiente.

Teniendo es código

```
let str = "Porfavor encuentra donde dice 'encuentra' en la cadena";
```

Al hacer lo siguiente:

```
str.lastIndexOf("encuentra")
```

da como resultado 31 que justamente es la posición donde se encuentra la última coincidencia, pero si realizo lo siguiente:

```
str.lastIndexOf("encuentra",18)
```

da como resultado 9 que justamente es donde comienza la última coincidencia, puesto que se especifica que comience la búsqueda a partir de la posición 18 hacia trás, ahora bien, si escribo el siguiente código...

```
str.lastIndexOf("encuentra",9)
```

yo esperaría que el resultado fuera -1 puesto que ese fragmento de cadena sería **"Porfavor e"**, y en ese fragmento no existe la palabra  **encuentra**, pero el resultado de ejecutar ese código da como resultado 9, pareciera que como encuentra la letra **e** ya con eso hace el match, pero según yo no debería de ser así, si no que debería de coincidir con la parabra exacta.

Tengo dudas sobre si ese resultado está correcto y en cuyo caso que sí, entonces podrían describir por qué sucede eso.

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comportamiento esperado es el que muestras ya que lo que busca es la subcadena y desde ese punto de referencia tiene acceso a ella de acuerdo a la lógica de buscar desde el punto de referencia que le das hasta el comienzo a  la primer ocurrencia. Lo podes ver mejor con código fíjate la diferencia con indexOf() y cuando LastIndexOf() pierde la referencia.La búsqueda se realiza empezando por el final de la cadena que realiza la llamada y se puede especificar que la búsqueda comience desde el indiceDesde.`cadena.lastIndexOf(valorBusqueda[, indiceDesde)`es desde el indiceDesde que comienza la búsqueda si le das como referencia la posición 9 esta sobre una letra que pertenece al Substring que buscas así puede reconocer al subString fijate en el ejemplo que doy el caso de dos encuentra  y a cual reconoce como primer subString encontrado

```js
let str = "Porfavor encuentra donde dice 'encuentra' en la cadena";

let b1=str.lastIndexOf("encuentra",18)
console.log('18',b1)
let w=str.lastIndexOf("encuentra",10)
console.log('busca desde posicion 10:',w)

let w1=str.lastIndexOf("encuentra",9)
console.log('busca desde posicion 9:',w1)
let y=str.lastIndexOf("encuentra",8)
console.log('busca desde posicion 8:',y)

let strPrueba="encuentra encuentra donde dice 'encuentra' en la cadena "
let xy=str.indexOf("encuentra",9);
console.log("encuentra desde 9 al primer encuentra indexOf :",xy);
let yz=str.lastIndexOf("encuentra",9)
console.log("encuentra desde 9 al primer encuentra lastIndexOf :",yz);
let x3 =str.indexOf("encuentra",8)
console.log("idenxOf encuentra 8:",x3)
let x2 =strPrueba.lastIndexOf("encuentra",15)
console.log("2 encuentra Last:",x2)
let x4 =strPrueba.indexOf("encuentra",15)
console.log("2 encuentra Index:",x4)
```

Comment: Creo comprender el funcionamiento, pero lo que me causa confusión precisamente es cuando se agrega el fromIndex, en otra respuesta sobre un tema similar decía que cuando se especifica el fromIndex, se hacía como un substring y sobre esa se realizaba la validación, pero ya mirando varios ejemplo alcanzo a mirar que no es así, pareciera que busca en toda la cadena y el parámetro fromIndex es sólo un delimitador de validación pero no un punto de comienzo de comprobación de valores,

Comment: Te lo aclaro en la respuesta es desde el indiceDesde que comienza la búsqueda si le das como referencia la posición 9 esta sobre una letra que pertenece al Substring que buscas así puede reconocer al subString

Comment: Entendido, muchas gracias, un saludo :-)

Comment: un gusto que mi respuesta te ayudara

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice @MabMab la búsqueda es de atrás hacia adelante, pero ten en cuenta que el índice empieza en 0 y que la lógica de la función es esta `str.lastIndexOf("encuentra", <=indice")`. Ese igual tal vez es el que te está confundiendo. Te dejo un ejemplo gráfico para que lo entiendas mejor.

```js
var cadena = "P23456789*123456789*123456789*";
console.log(cadena.lastIndexOf("*")); // mira en toda la cadena
console.log(cadena.lastIndexOf("*",9)); // indice <= 9 "P23456789*"
console.log(cadena.lastIndexOf("*",8)); // indice <= 8 "P23456789"
console.log(cadena.lastIndexOf("*",20)); // indice <=20 "P23456789*123456789*1"
console.log(cadena.lastIndexOf("*",19)); // indice <=20 "P23456789*123456789*"
console.log(cadena.lastIndexOf("*",18)); // indice <=20 "P23456789*123456789"
```